# Python: averaging timeseries data into bins of given duration

Tags: python

I think the definition of the problem is quite simple but I'm looking for a solution suitable for a very large dataset (20+ millions).

I have two lists: `stamps` containing `N` timestamps and `values` containing `N` scalar values.

I can easily plot these data to have a timeseries plot.

Now I would like to plot the average of `values` binned into 1-minute long bins (I usually have 50 values per minute but it happens that some are empty). Empty values leading to empty bins should make the average of that bin equal to zero.

How could I efficiently do that with a minimum of code?

Comment: I'll try to post an initial partial solution in the question asap.

Comment: what do you want done with empty values? Treat them as 0 and still average over 50? Or average over (num per bin - num empty)?

Comment: Empty values leading to empty bins should make the average of that bin equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
minute_bins = {}
averages    = {}

for i in range(len(values)):

    # Integer division
    minute = stamps[i] // 60

    if minute in minute_bins:
        minute_bins[minute].append(values[i])
    else:
        minute_bins[minute] = [values[i]]

for key in minute_bins:
    minute_values = minute_bins[key]
    averages[key] = float(sum(minute_values)) / len(minute_values)
```

Assuming you have your time stamps in the form of a number. I used `time.time()` to test my code, but any format where two time stamps 1 second apart differ by 1.0 should do.

Comment: I have my timestamp as `datetime.datetime` objects, so `stamp.timestamp()` should do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Cedric.  Because your dataset is so large, I think you need a solution that doesn't require reading all the values into a list and then later averaging them.  I'd use a simple averaging class that calculates a running average, something like this:

```
import collections

class averager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.avg = 0
        self.n = 0
    def add(self, x):
        self.avg = ((self.avg * self.n) + x) / (self.n + 1)
        self.n += 1

d = collections.defaultdict(averager)

for timestamp, value in zip(stamps, values):
    d[timestamp // 60].add(value)

for k in sorted(list(d.keys())):
    print(k, d[k].avg, sep="\t")
```

Your problem also seems amenable to parallel processing--split your dataset into chunks, calculate averages on each chunk running in parallel, and then average the averages together.

Hope this helps.